# Not getting fullscreen Android Studio TV

Tags: android-studio, fullscreen

Using Android Studio Hedgehog Android 14.
I am using TV 4K.
When Google TV loads, there is always the control bar on the right side of the screen.
I cannot get it to go full screen.
I have tried Borderless Gaming but it dims unless I turn HDR off.

I have tried Borderless Gaming but it dims unless I turn HDR off.